# Call backend API inside onDestroy in angular

Tags: angular, ngrx, angular-lifecycle-hooks

I need to call a backend API inside `onDestroy` in Angular. I need to save the state of something if the user leave the page, so I was thinking to do that call `onDestroy` lifecycle, but it's not working on production.
I tried with `canDeactivat` on the route as well, but it's not working:

This is the routing:

```js
{
  path: "",
  component: CardBuilderStepperComponent,
  pathMatch: "prefix",
  canDeactivate: [(component: CardBuilderStepperComponent) => component.canDeactivate()],
  ...
```

and this is the method:

```js
canDeactivate(): Promise<boolean> | boolean {
  return new Promise<boolean>((resolve) => {
    this.router.events
      .pipe(
        filter((event) => event instanceof NavigationEnd),
        take(1)
      )
      .subscribe((event) => {
        const urlAfterRedirects = (event as NavigationEnd).urlAfterRedirects;

        if (urlAfterRedirects === "/") this.navigationService.updateSnapshotNoChangeLocation();

        resolve(true);
      });
  });
}

ngOnDestroy(): void {
  this.store.dispatch(LayoutActions.closeExpanseBar());
  console.log("destroy");
}
```

It's not working like that, but it works if `resolve(true)` goes outside the subscription. But I need that `resolve(true)` and I need to destroy the component only when the backend API is done. If I leave it outside the subscription, the component gets destroyed before the API backend get called.

Any idea on how can I solve that?